# Storing nodejs fs.readfile's result in a variable and pass to global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass the contents of fs.readfile out of the scope of the readfile method and store it in a variable similar to.

```
var a;

function b () {
    var c = "from scope of b";
    a = c;
}
b();
```

Then I can console.log(a); or pass it to another variable.

My question:

Is there a way to do this with fs.readFile so that the contents (data) get passed to the global variable global_data.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var global_data;

fs.readFile("example.txt", "UTF8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err };
    global_data = data;
});

console.log(global_data);  // undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You are trying to access something from an asynchronous context in a synchronous one, which doesn't work, here a pic (read the comment below, too) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34161451/5925094

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem you have isn't a problem of scope but of order of operations.

As readFile is asynchronous, `console.log(global_data);` occurs before the reading, and before the `global_data = data;` line is executed.

The right way is this :

```
fs.readFile("example.txt", "UTF8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err };
    global_data = data;
    console.log(global_data);
});
```

In a simple program (usually not a web server), you might also want to use the synchronous operation [readFileSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) but it's generally preferable not to stop the execution.

Using readFileSync, you would do

```
var global_data = fs.readFileSync("example.txt").toString();
```

Comment: Right Im just wondering if its possible to pass data variable contents to the global global_data variable. The console.log(global_data) was just to show that it comes up undefined.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my answer. It's possible to pass data variable contents to the global global_data variable, there's no problem in that. But the problem you have is that you execute the console.log before you fill the variable.

Comment: Ok, so that's the whole asynchronous thing. But using readFileSync doesn't seem to help. Is it possible to fill the variable before executing console.log. I guess is my question.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Using readFileSync and converting to string doesnt help since my content in object.