# Node Express put HTML code in a variable (not sent to display)

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have found only the code to display a HTML file :

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

 res.sendFile('index.html');

});
```

While I want just to get the HTML in a variable (to sent it later only if needed).
So I look for something like this (with express.js) :

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

 var example = res.readFile('index.html');

});
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a duplicate for this, but every question I find assumes you've already figured out that you need to use the `fs` module and not the response object.

Comment: ok I have found myself, as I knew that I had to use fs (thanks) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494226/storing-nodejs-fs-readfiles-result-in-a-variable-and-pass-to-global-variable